# How do I break out of a loop without first appending to my list?

Tags: python, list

How do I prevent the following code from appending the break command "N" to the list, and therefore printing "N"?

```
xlist=[]
item=str(input("Item to add? (\"N\" to quit)"))
xlist.append(item)
while item != "N":
    item=str(input("Item to add? (\"N\" to quit)"))
    xlist.append(item)
    if item == "N":
        break

print(xlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simplify your program this way:

```
xlist=[]
item=input("Item to add? (\"N\" to quit)")
while item != "N":
    xlist.append(item)
    item=input("Item to add? (\"N\" to quit)")
```

Edit: Removed superfluous `str()` calls as suggested in a comment.

Comment: the `str()` calls are redundant (assuming python 3; in python 2 should use `raw_input`)

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, `item != "N":` will never become false, because you manually break out of the loop.

A better way of having a while lop that will end upon a certain input, which avoids having two input statements would be to use an infinite while loop (`while True`), and then break out when the desired condition is met:

```
xlist=[]
while True:
    item=str(input("Item to add? (\"N\" to quit)"))
    if item.upper() == "N":
        break
    xlist.append(item)

print(xlist)
```

Also, I added the `upper()` so that it will accept either `n` or `N`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips:

- you can use `'this "kind" of string'` to avoid `\`
- you can actually avoid having the same line of code by re-introducing an if statement

  - If you're using Python2 (as a beginner you shouldn't be) you should be using `raw_input`, not `str(input(...))`. If you're using Python3, you don't need to cast to str, it's already a str.
  - You can use the `.lower()` (or `.upper()`) method to let the user use `n` or `N`.

This is what that looks like:

```
xlist = []
item = ''
while True:
    item = input('Item to add? ("N" to quit): ')
    if item.lower() == 'n':
        break
    else:
        xlist.append(item)
```